# Restart button not working properly (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm doing a 2D game and I got the main canvas with the game screen, and another canvas which is the game over screen.

Currently the code I have on the game over script is:

```
public class GameOverScreen : MonoBehaviour
{
public Text pointsText;
void Start()
{
gameObject.SetActive(false);
}
public void Setup()
{
gameObject.SetActive(true);
}
public void RestartButton()
{
SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
}
}
```

The "RestartButton()" loads the active scene, however when I click on the button, it indeed goes back to the game screen but quickly shows up the game over screen within miliseconds.

My question is, how can I make it so it only shows the main game canvas and hides the game over canvas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried rather putting this `gameObject.SetActive(false)` into `Awake` instead? ;)

Comment: @derHugo Yes. And it still gives the same problem.. whenever I click restart it shows the game screen but for just some milli seconds and it goes back to game over screen once again.

Comment: Well then have you tried to simply already disable that in the scene when you save it? The issue is clearly that until the entire scene finished loading and all Awake calls are done your object isn't deactivated yet .. simply save it as already inactive right from the beginning

Comment: The background is already disabled in the scene, but the canvas is not. When I disable the canvas, the game over screen doesn't even appear. I apologize but I'm new to Unity/C# so I don't understand the smallest of the problems.

Comment: What @derHugo meant was not disabling the canvas, but the GameObject that you would want to disable in the Awake method. Then it should not show up at all when loading the scene.